# I can't delete users from my app in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication

I am developing a webpage for elderly people in Django for my internship. I received some code already done from another coworker but for some reason when I try to delete users from the /admin site it gives me and error.

In addition, I only have one form to register and login in the webpage but it gives another error.

login view:

```
def login_view(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(reverse('portada'))
mensaje = 'El usuario no estaba registrado'
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    dia = request.POST.get('dia')
    mes = request.POST.get('mes')
    year = request.POST.get('year')
    password =  dia + mes + year + 'year'
    user = authenticate( username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:            
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(reverse('portada'))
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})    
    else:
        mensaje = 'Se va a registrar un usuario'
        form = RegistroUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
            dia = form.cleaned_data['dia']
            mes = form.cleaned_data['mes']
            year = form.cleaned_data['year']

            password =  dia + mes + year + 'year'
            user_model = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            user_model.save()
            
            user_profile = UserProfile()
            
            user_profile.user = user_model
        
            user_profile.save()
          
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            dia = request.POST.get('dia')
            mes = request.POST.get('mes')
            year = request.POST.get('year')
            password =  dia + mes + year + 'year'
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                mensaje = 'Se va a registrar un usuario12'
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    mensaje = 'Se va a registrar un usuario123'
                    return redirect(reverse('portada'))
                
            return render(request, 'blog/crearVivencia.html', {'mensaje': mensaje})
        pass    
return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'mensaje': mensaje})
```

My Register form:

```
class RegistroUserForm(forms.Form):

username = forms.CharField(min_length=3, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
dia = forms.CharField(min_length=1, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
mes = forms.CharField(min_length=1, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
year = forms.CharField(min_length=4, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

when I try to log in I get this error: IntegrityError at /login/
UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

In addition, when I try to delete SOME of the users from the /admin site, I get this error:

IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles', default = 
'profiles/avatar.jpg', blank=True, null=True)
num = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
localidad = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = 'Dato sin rellenar 
')
edad = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = 'Dato sin rellenar ')
biografia = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default = 'Dato sin 
rellenar ')
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Perfil de usuario'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Perfiles de usuarios'
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

class Document(models.Model):
docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')


class Tag(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Etiqueta'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Etiquetas'    

    
class Vivencia(models.Model):
autor = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
viveFoto = models.FileField(upload_to='viveFoto', blank=True, null=True)
tituloImag = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = ' ')
text = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(
    default=timezone.now)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(
    blank=True, null=True)
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Vivencia'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Vivencias'
def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()
def author(self):
    self.authors = author()
    self.save()
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
#def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    #return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
def get_string_tags(self):
    return ', '.join([tag.name for tag in self.tags.all()])
```

This might be quite tricky to understand, if you need any clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you show your models? For the first error it seems that `username` field have `unique=True` attribute and the form probablu returning empty string (or name already taken). As for second error - can you show full exception trace?

Comment: I edited the post with the models, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Integrity error occurs when you have more than 2 users with same `username`, either they maybe blank or duplicated, can you check from looking into database rows for users

second option would be if you don't care about data just delete all the rows from shell (command below) and add few more users and try to delete it.

Command to delete user from shell

```
python manage.py shell

import_your_user_here Ex-> from apps.core import User`

User.objects.all().delete()
```

Comment: Admin user delete action should anyway work. If it's not, the option to delete users from shell will not help to solve the source problem.

Comment: Charnet, i have looked into some scenario where people apply dump to their database, and at that time if models are not configured properly you will end up having junk data, and admin throws error on doing CRUD operation

Answer (score 1):

At this line of your code:

```
user_model = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
user_model.save()
```

You are creating another user. This is the reason for IntegrityError at /login/ UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

While login, you can try to get the user like below:

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception occurred in fetching user: %s"%(e))
```

If you are giving a Sign Up feature for new user, writing logic in another function is better and then call that function wherever you want to create a new user.

From admin panel, deleting users is resulting in error because user is mapped to another tables as Foreign Key and the system may break. So, you should check models.py for all apps in the project and find which models are dependent on user to understand criticality.

If you have to delete the users, then drop the whole table (if data is not important or backed up). Delete all migration files, make modifications in models.py, make new migrations, run these new migrations and then re-enter the data. This is not a lot of work if you have automatic database insertion file written for all your models; but you have to remove the user being used as Foreign Key in data as well.